# Geting Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected ":" (25:13) while trying to get wordpress post with Axios in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, axios, wordpress-rest-api

I'm trying to get a list of WordPress posts in React using Axios, I try importing the necessary files and I also install Axios with npm i Axios, but when I start the server I go an error **Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected ":" (24:13)** I write the below codes

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Intropage from "./components/intropage";
import "./customcss/style.css";
import axios from 'axios';

 
class Home extends React.Component {

    constructor( props ) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            loading: false,
            posts: [],
            error: ''
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const wordPressSiteUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/mysite_api';
        this.setState( state: { loading: true }, callback: () => {
            axios
            .get( url:`${wordPressSiteUrl}/wp-json/wp/v2/posts`)
                .then( onfulfilled: res => {
                this.setState( state: { loading: false, posts: res.data})
            })
        .catch( onrejected: error => this.setState( state: { loading: false, error: error.response.data }))
        });
    }
  
        render() {
          
    return (
      <>
  
      <Intropage />
            
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

I'm getting this error on the browser

```
Failed to compile
./src/home.js
Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected ":" (24:13)

  22 |         this.setState( state: { loading: true }, callback: () => {
  23 |             axios
> 24 |             .get( url:`${wordPressSiteUrl}/wp-json/wp/v2/posts`)
     |             ^
  25 |                 .then( onfulfilled: res => {
  26 |                 this.setState( state: { loading: false, posts: res.data})
  27 |             })
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to put the `url:` in the `.get` params.  You can simply pass the `URL` and get your results like so:

```
    componentDidMount() {
        const wordPressSiteUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/mysite_api';
        this.setState({ loading: true }, () => {
            axios
            .get(`${wordPressSiteUrl}/wp-json/wp/v2/posts`)
                .then(res => {
                 console.log(res)
                this.setState({ loading: false, posts: res.data})
            })
        .catch( error => this.setState({loading: false, error: error.response.data }))
        });
    }
```

EDIT:  Judging off your current error, I would suggest you `console.log()` your `res` and see what is going on.  If the API is correctly working, you'll see some data structure.  You didn't specify whether or not it's sending over `JSON`, so I am not sure what is suppose to be coming over.  If your `res` is undefined, you may need to check out to see what is going on the `Wordpress` side of things.

Comment: I'm getting the same error.

Comment: after adding your change I got this error "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')"

Comment: You don't need to explicitly call ````state```` - ````this.setState```` is already doing that magic.  You just need to update object of ````state```` since it's already been explicitly defined.  I also turned the remainder of the ````promise```` functions into single expression arrow functions.

Comment: You need to see what is going on with the ````response```` or in this case, ````res````.   I updated and explained my code above.

Comment: i'm getting this error on the res GET http://localhost:8080/mysite_api/wp-json/wp/v2/posts net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: Well, glad I helped you with the api request.  The issue is definitely on the ````WordPress```` side of things.  I can't help you much there, at least in this thread.  If you feel I helped you with your problem, be sure to accept this as the right answer.  Thanks!